# Validate uniqueness between 2 columns from different tables through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, indexing, unique

I have a design issue to handle a uniqueness constraint on a postgres db in a rails app.

I have:

- a `companies` table, which has `firm_id` and `name` column
- a `firms` table with a `group_id` column (`id` linked to `companies.firm_id`)
- a `groups` table (`id` linked to `firms.group_id`)

I would like to ensure uniqueness of the `company.name` + `company.firm.group_id`, so some kind of multi columns unique index across two tables.

Is that even possible?

I don't know/think how/if we can do that natively with postgres indexes, so the solutions I see are :

- replicating redundant `group_id` column on the `companies` table, which causes maintenance issues of data synchronisation/reliability between those 2 columns. This is what I do now, and it's not ideal.
- not using the database index, and rely on rails validation only, that can be query-heavy, and suffer from race conditions on mass updates

I don't particularly like these solutions, does someone think of something else we can do about it ?

Answer (score 0):

A regular `constraint` cannot span multiple tables, but you can use a [`constraint trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) to enforce completely arbitrary constraint logic. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/jcRaaL-g)

```
create table groups(   
    id serial primary key );
create table firms(    
    id serial primary key,
    group_id int references groups(id) );
create table companies(
    id serial primary key,
    firm_id int references firms(id),
    name text );
```

```
create function f_unique_company_name_per_group()returns trigger as $f$
declare current_company_group int:=(select group_id 
                                    from firms 
                                    where id=new.firm_id);
begin 
    if exists(select from companies inner join firms
             on  companies.firm_id=firms.id
             and companies.name=new.name
             and companies.id is distinct from new.id
             and firms.group_id=current_company_group) then
        raise exception using 
            detail=format('Company name %L already exists in group %L',
                               new.name,
                               current_company_group),
            errcode = 23505, --'unique_violation',
            column='name',
            table=TG_TABLE_NAME,
            schema=TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,
            datatype='text',
            constraint='t_unique_company_name_per_group';
    end if;
    return new;
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create constraint trigger t_unique_company_name_per_group 
after insert or update on companies
for each row execute function f_unique_company_name_per_group();
```

```
insert into groups values (1),(2);
insert into firms values (1,1),(2,1),(3,1);
insert into companies values (1,1,'company1'),(2,2,'company2');
--different company, different firm, but the same name within group:
insert into companies values (3,3,'company1');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  23505
> DETAIL:  Company name 'company1' already exists in group '1'
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f_unique_company_name_per_group() line 9 at RAISE
> ```